# Bug in converting matlab code to python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I have

```
mask = 255 ('000000FF')
r = uint8(bitand(bitshift(rgb, -16), mask))
```

This code is written in matlab. Now is this code correct in Python:

```
r = (rgb>>16 & mask).astype('uint8')
```

For rgb = 1884829820, I am getting 88 as the answer for matlab while I am getting 256 for Python. I don't understand why?

Comment: Note that SO isn't a free code translation service so you should post your own attempt at coding this in Python, and explain the problem you're having. Are you doing this in plain Python or in Numpy?

Comment: Search for bit operations in python and and an attempt first. If you have further problems it's of course fine to make a question.

Comment: @PM2Ring - in Numpy. I am trying to convert big chuck of code from matlab to python.I am not understanding how this line is implemented?

Comment: okay! I am trying. I'll update.

Comment: Thanks. Your update should include a _small_ sample array so we can see the exact format & datatype of your data. BTW, are you sure `mask` is 256? A mask of 255 (0xff) would make more sense.

Comment: @talos1904 In the update, try to find a more descriptive title for your question as well :)

Comment: @PM2Ring - I have figured out the way to do it but I am getting different answers. Is this correct

Comment: @Grimmy - I have figured out the way to do it but I am getting different answers. Is this correct?

Comment: Your Python Numpy code looks ok. I assume this code is supposed to extract the red value from a RGB color value stored as a 24 bit unsigned integer. And that `mask` is 255. However, 1884829820 == 0x7058387c, which is too big to be a 24 bit color. I guess it could be a color with an alpha (transparency) channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mask = 0xFF # = 255 also works
rgb = 1884829820
r = rgb >> 16 & mask
print(r)
```

Outputs:

```
88
```

`0xFF` is 255, not 256. That is your problem.

256 will create the mask `0b100000000`

Comment: Yes! I understood the code as well as the problem. Thank you! :)  It's time to savor.

Answer (score 2):

I assume this code is supposed to extract the red value from a RGB color value stored as a 24 bit unsigned integer, with red in te high bits and blue in the low bits. So `mask` needs to be 255 (0xff in hexadecimal) to capture the 8 bits of data from the red channel after we shift them into place.

Here's a small Numpy demo.

```
import numpy as np

np.set_printoptions(formatter={'int': hex})

colors = np.array([0x123456, 0x789abc, 0xdef012, 1884829820], dtype=np.uint32)
print(colors, colors.dtype)

mask = 255
reds = ((colors >>16) & mask).astype(np.uint8)
print(reds, reds.dtype)
```

**output**

```
[0x123456 0x789abc 0xdef012 0x7058387c] uint32
[0x12 0x78 0xde 0x58] uint8
```

I've used hex output to make it clear that we're actually getting the red channel bits. Note that 0x58 == 88 in decimal.